# How to use Vuelidate for an Object of an Array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuelidate

I have the following vue array;

```
    server: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Name A', ipaddress: '192.168.1.1', status: true, applied: true, modal: false },
          { id: 1, name: 'Name A', ipaddress: '192.168.1.1', status: true, applied: true, modal: false },
        ]
```

I use this array to show these information on a data table. Users can add new rows to this table, that is, they can push the array. In addition, they can delete the rows they want from the table with the splice method. Finally, each row has an edit button. Since these buttons are connected to the elements in the array with the v-model, users can make changes on the row they want in the modal window that opens.
Adding and editing operations are carried out with two different modalities that open when the button is pressed.

In line with all this information, there is a question I want to ask. How can I write validation with Vuelidation to an array where new rpws can be added continuously? Here is my vuelidation functions;

```
validations: {
  server: {
    required,
    $each: {
      name: {
        required
      },
      ipaddress: {
        required
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As an example, I just defined the `required` attribute for two elements. And here is how I use them in my add and edit modals;

```
    <div>
        <div">
            <label>Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input v-if="server[i].modal" v-model="server[i].name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <small class="error-msg" v-if="!$v.server[i].name.required && $v.server[i].name.$dirty">Name is required.</small>
    </div>
```

Here is how I add a new row to the table;

```
  addNewRow(){
    this.server.push({
      name: "",
      ipaddress: "",
      status: true,
      applied: false,
      modal: false
    });
  },
```

And now I have this error;

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

I think I'm missing an important part here so how can I make this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello
how are you adding new item ?

Is the code working before you added new item on the table?

Comment: I have updated my question so you can see my add function. The parts that I explained are working perfectly fine. I can edit the existing rows and add new rows.

Comment: Help you better understand
1. You want validation rules for edit/add ?
2. Everything else is working except the error you are experiencing ?

Comment: That is true. Everything is working. What I want to do is to add vuelidation to my Add and Edit modals so that I can check if the user types the correct IP address format for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your add modal might be delay with the template so no server[i] item would be defined. I would suggest using a different variable for add (newItem = {name: '', ...})